# Remove correlation values from table if they are not significant (in another table)

Tags: r, dataframe, formatting

I have a 100 x 100 table containing correlation values, and a sister table (also 100 x 100) containing the P-values of those correlations.

I would like to print the correlation table, but only those cells that have a P < 0.05.

Input: 2 tables (correlation values and P values)

```
>Corr_matrix
        value1  value2  value3  value4
value1  1.000   0.136   0.078   -0.048
value2  0.136   1.000   0.011   -0.036
value3  0.078   0.011   1.000   0.000
value4  -0.048  -0.036  0.000   1.000


>P_adjusted             
        value1  value2  value3  value4
value1  0.000   0.004   0.002   0.001
value2  0.004   0.000   0.003   0.010
value3  0.002   0.003   0.000   0.950
value4  0.001   0.010   0.950   0.000


>results            
        value1  value2  value3  value4
value1  1.000   0.136   0.078   -0.048
value2  0.136   1.000   0.011   -0.036
value3  0.078   0.011   1.000   NA
value4  -0.048  -0.036  NA      1.000
```

I was thinking of something on the lines of:

```
P_adjusted[ P_adjusted > 0.05 ] <- NA # turn non-significant values to NA
isnotNA <- !is.na(as.matrix(P_adjusted)) # grab positions of what is not an NA
results <- Corr_matrix[isnotNA=="TRUE"] # use those positions to subset correlation matrix
```

This does not work, and I can kind of see why, but this is not clear to me yet. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just compare your significance level in the one matrix with and set them to `NA` in the other, accordingly.

```
vals[p.adj > .05] <- NA
vals
#   value1 value2 value3 value4
# 1  1.000  0.136  0.078 -0.048
# 2  0.136  1.000  0.011 -0.036
# 3  0.078  0.011  1.000     NA
# 4 -0.048 -0.036     NA  1.000
```

---

*Data:*

```
vals <- structure(list(value1 = c(1, 0.136, 0.078, -0.048), value2 = c(0.136, 
1, 0.011, -0.036), value3 = c(0.078, 0.011, 1, NA), value4 = c(-0.048, 
-0.036, NA, 1)), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")

p.adj <- structure(list(value1 = c(0, 0.004, 0.002, 0.001), value2 = c(0.004, 
0, 0.003, 0.01), value3 = c(0.002, 0.003, 0, 0.95), value4 = c(0.001, 
0.01, 0.95, 0)), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Gahhhh, so simple! Thank you, and sorry for the silly question.